# How to change the access modifier of a user control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, class-design, access-modifiers

I have a user control created in xaml, lets name it "View". In the View.xaml.cs I changed the access modifier for the class View to internal:

```
internal partial class View : ViewBase { ... }
```

After changing the access modifier the compiler states the error:

> Partial declarations of 'A.B.View' have
>   conflicting accessibility modifiers

My first guess was that the view has to be made internal via the xaml code. So I added two lines of xaml:

```
x:Name="View"
x:FieldModifier="internal"
```

But this did not fix the error. Where do I have to change the access modifier to make a view internal?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The class modifier is done through "x:ClassModifier".

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754029.aspx for more information.

Answer (score -4):

because its a partial class, another file exists with the line;

```
public partial class View : ViewBase { ... }
```

you can search the file and change public to internal, it should solve the problem

Comment: It's a generated file from XAML, so you cannot find the file.